# Keyboard visibility

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

For a WP7 app, I have a text field that requires input.
Planning on two ways of allowing this.   Firstly via keyboard as per the norm.

Secondly just above the text field field, I  have a set of buttons (in a horizontal scrolling listbox) that are visible when the text field has focus that allows the user to scroll and select -  press a button and I fill the text field (text depends on which button has been pressed)

I have this all going but what I would like to do is ideally, allow the user to scroll along the buttons whilst they are entering text into the textbox and still have the keyboard up.  That is they can choose to slide along to a button and click one and then their text will be entered for them.

What I am finding is that as they move to  the buttons and slide along, the text field loses focus and the keyboard disappears. It's not a big deal, but just looks a little awkward - which is  shame because aside form this I am getting the behaviour as I want.

Just wondering if there is any way that I can work around this and somehow keep the keyboard up whilst they slide along my horizontal listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Applications don't have direct control over the keyboard. It will show when a text control has focus and hide when one doesn't.

So, the only thing you can do is to play with setting focus on your TextBox.